# Initialize modules asynchronously

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a function to require my modules (middlewares and controllers) but I want to initialize middlewares first.

My code bellow initialize both modules in the same time :

```
function loadModule(app, modulePath) {
  var folder = path.join(__dirname, modulePath);
  fs.readdir(folder, function(err, files) {
    _.forEach(files, function(file) {
      var controllerPath = path.join(folder, file);
      fs.stat(controllerPath, function(err, stats) {
        if (stats.isFile() && file !== 'Controller.js') {
          var loadingModulePath = './' + modulePath + '/' + file;
          console.log('Loading module : ' + loadingModulePath);
          var Module = require(loadingModulePath)(app);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

loadModule(app, 'middlewares');
loadModule(app, 'controllers');
```

Issue : sometimes controllers are initialized in first, sometimes that are middlewares...

Edit #1 :

```
const express   = require('express'),
  app       = express(),
  async     = require('async');


function loadModule(module, app) {
  var folder = path.join(__dirname, module);
  fs.readdir(folder, function(err, files) {
    _.forEach(files, function(file) {
      var controllerPath = path.join(folder, file);
      fs.stat(controllerPath, function(err, stats) {
        if (stats.isFile() && file !== 'Controller.js') {
          var loadingModulePath = './' + module + '/' + file;
          console.log('Loading module : ' + loadingModulePath);
          var Module = require(loadingModulePath)(app);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

async.series([
  function(callback, app) {
    loadModule('middlewares', app);
    callback(null);
  },
  function(callback, app) {
    loadModule('controllers', app);
    callback(null);
  }
], function(err, results) {
  console.log(err, results);
});
```

Issue edit #1 : `app is undefined...`

Comment: Is there a specific reason to make it this complicated? What speaks against simply requiring the modules you need, in the order you need them, like pretty much everybody else does?

Comment: Or, put differently. `require()` is a synchronous function for a reason. You components cannot work until the modules they depend on are loaded. There is a dependency graph of such requirements that needs to be worked through before your program can start to do any work of its own. It does not make sense to make any part of this process asynchronous, and even if you out your callbacks here, it would not save one iota of time. So... let it go, would be my advice.

Comment: I'm working on a framework and I'd like to generate controllers using command lines. But I need first to load modules in a specific order...

Comment: What about using async.series (https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#seriestasks-callback) ?

Comment: See edit #1. It doesn't work with `async.series`.